# Jssor Thumbnail Navigation Doesn't Slide/Drag

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, jssor

We are implementing a Jssor slider on our website. Everything was working good, but while we were adjusting for design and images the thumbnail navigation stopped moving.

The page is here: http://visionsunltd.com/CMS/advertising-gallery

```
<script src="http://visionsunltd.com/js/jssor.slider.min.js"></script>
<script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

            var _SlideshowTransitions = [
            //Fade in R

                {$Duration: 2000, $During: { $Left: [0.3, 0.7] }, $Fade:true, $Easing: { $Left: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInCubic, $Opacity: $JssorEasing$.$EaseLinear }, $ScaleHorizontal: 0.3, $Opacity: 2 }
                ];

            var options = {
                $AutoPlay: true,                                    //[Optional] Whether to auto play, to enable slideshow, this option must be set to true, default value is false
                $AutoPlayInterval: 4000,                            //[Optional] Interval (in milliseconds) to go for next slide since the previous stopped if the slider is auto playing, default value is 3000
                $PauseOnHover: 1,                                //[Optional] Whether to pause when mouse over if a slider is auto playing, 0 no pause, 1 pause for desktop, 2 pause for touch device, 3 pause for desktop and touch device, default value is 1

                $DragOrientation: 3,                                //[Optional] Orientation to drag slide, 0 no drag, 1 horizental, 2 vertical, 3 either, default value is 1 (Note that the $DragOrientation should be the same as $PlayOrientation when $DisplayPieces is greater than 1, or parking position is not 0)
                $ArrowKeyNavigation: true,                          //[Optional] Allows keyboard (arrow key) navigation or not, default value is false
                $SlideDuration: 800,                                //Specifies default duration (swipe) for slide in milliseconds

                $SlideshowOptions: {                                //[Optional] Options to specify and enable slideshow or not
                    $Class: $JssorSlideshowRunner$,                 //[Required] Class to create instance of slideshow
                    $Transitions: _SlideshowTransitions,            //[Optional] An array of slideshow transitions to play slideshow
                    $TransitionsOrder: 1,                           //[Optional] The way to choose transition to play slide, 1 Sequence, 0 Random
                    $ShowLink: true                                    //[Optional] Whether to bring slide link on top of the slider when slideshow is running, default value is false
                },

                $ArrowNavigatorOptions: {                       //[Optional] Options to specify and enable arrow navigator or not
                    $Class: $JssorArrowNavigator$,              //[Optional] Class to create arrow navigator instance
                    $ChanceToShow: 1                               //[Required] 0 Never, 1 Mouse Over, 2 Always
                },

                $ThumbnailNavigatorOptions: {                       //[Optional] Options to specify and enable thumbnail navigator or not
                    $Class: $JssorThumbnailNavigator$,              //[Required] Class to create thumbnail navigator instance
                    $ChanceToShow: 2,                               //[Required] 0 Never, 1 Mouse Over, 2 Always

                    $ActionMode: 1,                                 //[Optional] 0 None, 1 act by click, 2 act by mouse hover, 3 both, default value is 1
                    $SpacingX: 8,                                   //[Optional] Horizontal space between each thumbnail in pixel, default value is 0
                    $DisplayPieces: 10,                             //[Optional] Number of pieces to display, default value is 1
                    $ParkingPosition: 360                          //[Optional] The offset position to park thumbnail
                }
            };

            var jssor_slider1 = new $JssorSlider$("slider1_container", options);
            //responsive code begin
            //you can remove responsive code if you don't want the slider scales while window resizes
            function ScaleSlider() {
                var parentWidth = jssor_slider1.$Elmt.parentNode.clientWidth;
                if (parentWidth)
                    jssor_slider1.$SetScaleWidth(Math.max(Math.min(parentWidth, 1000), 300));
                else
                    window.setTimeout(ScaleSlider, 30);
            }

            ScaleSlider();

            if (!navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPhone|iPod|iPad|BlackBerry|IEMobile)/)) {
                $(window).bind('resize', ScaleSlider);
            }


            //if (navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPhone|iPod|iPad)/)) {
            //    $(window).bind("orientationchange", ScaleSlider);
            //}
            //responsive code end
        });
</script>
```

Any ideas on why the thumbnail navigation doesn't move and we can't drag it to get to the other thumbnails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked your slider, there are totally 9 slides.

In the `$ThumbnailNavigatorOptions`, you set `$DisplayPieces: 10`. That's to say, the total 9 thumbnails are all displayed already, there is no chance to drag to display more.

Please set `$DisplayPieces: 8`, thus you can get 8 displayed and another one hidden, then you can drag to loop thumbnails.